# Set breakpoint on all found text in Visual Studio just like "Bookmark All" in find window

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ide

How to set breakpoints on all found text in Visual Studio just like "Bookmark All" sets bookmarks on all found text in "Find in Files" window?